# Is it possible to add an image field into Freeform pro?

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is it possible to add an mage field into Freeform pro? Maybe a footer image field.

The reason for this is, that we are doing forms for business awards and need to have sponsors logo on all the pages.

Comment: Your question is poorly worded. Although I think I get what you wanted to ask, I don't understand the desired outcome at all from your question. FreeFrom primarily deals with form input and email output, not template output to a URL other than frontend rendering of the same inputted data.

Comment: @Priti Why you want to include in Freeform. You can just create simple Image field for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re referring to using the new Freeform (“Next”), you can simply add an HTML special field type to your form in Composer and set an image there. You can ALSO just hard code image into a formatting template for forms.

If using Freeform Classic (old Pro or Free), there isn’t an HTML field but you can also just add the logo image code to your main EE template(s) the form sits in.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a channel to create your form pages, and use Freeform's fieldtype to select the form you want to use in your entry. This means you can populate your entry/page content using normal EE fields the inserting the form wherever you want it to appear.

Comment: I'm new to this so would need more guidance. Is is possible for you to give more guidance on it?